# AWS Elemental Media Store credentials unavailable

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-media-live, aws-elemental, aws-mediastore

So, I'm creating a nodejs application that uses AWS Media Live and AWS Media Store to live stream audio and video.

I created the media live channel, the input and the media store container correctly.
The role that I used for the channel has the MediaStoreFullAcces permission, so it can read from and write to the container. So far so good.

If I start the stream with obs studio, using the RTMP push url and the stream key and everything seems to be working fine. But, if I take a look at the channel's logs, it shows me this error, saying it can't write to media store:

```
OutputDataBackground failed to send file for URL [mediastoressl://.../720p30_00028.ts], after [10] attempts, error [EMS credentials unavailable]
```

It doesn't create the .m3u8 file in the container also.

**My doubt is, what are the EMS credentials, if not the permissions from the role?**

I can't find anywhere in AWS console to add credential or change the security.
Anybody who could help me please?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your inquiry. You can check the following documentation to ensure that all the permissions required to write out to MediaStore from a MediaLive Channel's associated Role exist. If the Role's policy does not include the Actions listed in the table for MediaStore and/or the Resource statement is incorrect or too strict then MediaLive will not be able to write to the Destination.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/trusted-entity-requirements.html

You can optionally configure each Output Group's credentials individually using the Credentials fields for each Destination. This method requires the AWS Parameter Store for securely storing the AWS Secret Access Key of the IAM User that MediaLive will use to write to MediaStore.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/medialive/latest/ug/requirements-for-EC2.html

Please let me know if I can be of any further assistance.